# MUI avoid helperText to change width of input field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the `helpertext` of the mui `textfield` component to display validation errors. Unfortunately the `helpertext` is increasing the width of the `textfield`. I am using the "fullWidth" attribute.

If there is no error, no helper text is shown (image 1). If input validation fails, error is shown but the the textfield should remain the same size (image 2).

[image: Without error, correct width]

[image: With error, wrong width]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with GWT MaterialTextBox. I managed to solve my problem by setting a fixed width (e.g. 300px) for the text box.